# How to keep the same python console on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I love pycharm as it is very useful for my data analysis.

However there is something that I still can't figure out a big problem.
When I start to save a lot of variables, it is very useful. But sometimes, especially when I want to run a piece of row using seaborn and create a new graph, sometimes, all my variables disseapear and I have to reload them again from scratch.

I'd like to know, do you know a way to keep the data stored and run only a piece of my code without getting this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like you want a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what issue you are having, but from the sounds of it you just need to store a bunch of data and only use some of it.

If that's the case, I would save files which each set of data and then import the one you want to use at that time.

If you stick to the same data names then your program can just do something like:

```
import data_435 as data
# now your code can always access data.whatever_var
# even though you have 435 different data sets
```

Comment: I'll give it a try !! 

Well, to explain it more rigorously, I like to run a piece of code one after the other. I use the same python console, all my variables are stored into the same console and I can use execute selection in python console. 

This is very useful, but when I misusing seaborn (and I misuse everytime as I'm learning it), I try to do "execute selection in python console" and a new python console will show up on Pycharm. Thus, I have to reload the whole data that were stored on my previous python console and rerun them. I'll try what you said.